# Per-declaration rustfmt configuration

Tags: rust

I have a large array of structs that formats poorly using rustfmt's default indent setting. For this particular declaration, `Visual` indenting is more appropriate.

Is it possible to configure formatting per-declaration using attributes so I can supply an indent setting (or any setting) on a per-need basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

FWIW you can put `#[rustfmt_skip]` or `#[cfg_attr(rustfmt, rustfmt_skip)]` on expressions or items to skip the formatting.

```rust
fn foo() {
    #[rustfmt_skip]
    let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
             6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
}
```